# how can i change the font size of a text file in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm specifically talking about the text font size of  .txt files in Eclipse. I've already changed the default font size for .java files but any file with .txt is unchanged and really small.

Comment: select General → Appearance → Colors and Fonts → Basic → Text Font.

Comment: @Abi thank you! Can you repost as a full answer so I can select it as best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ian
(Posting as answer)

Follow this

select General → Appearance → Colors and Fonts → Basic → Text Font.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this :

> General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts